# How to catch all data from @foreach loop and pass it into <input> value? - laravel

Tags: laravel

So im new to laravel and im trying to get a data from 'cart' table in database with @foreach, and i try this..

```
<form action="{{ url('/checkout') }}" method="post">
@method('POST')
@csrf

@foreach ( $datacart as $keycart)
<input type="hidden" value="{{ $keycart->nama_produk}}" name="nama_produk"/>
@endforeach

</form>
```

this is the [cart table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Y89EJ.png)

and it does pass all the 'nama_produk' into 'input' value, but the problem is, when i try to insert all the 'cart' data into 'checkout' table in database, it only insert 1 data. and i try to check what data does it pass using dd(); , it only pass the [latest row](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3Q03x.png) data from 'cart' table.

so is there a way to pass all the data that i get from @foreach and keep it into 'input' value?

and is there a best way to insert data into database without using input hidden? because in this condition i dont have choice

thank you!

Comment: How ```$datacart``` is constructed inside the controller ?

Comment: ``name="nama_produk[]"`` !!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change the input

```
<input type="hidden" value="{{ $keycart->nama_produk}}" name="nama_produk"/>
```

to

```
<input type="hidden" value="{{ $keycart->nama_produk}}" name="nama_produk[]"/>
```

then you will get all the data in controller as an array.

then loop the data name_produk and insert to db

```
foreach($request->nama_produk as $row){
 your query here...
}
```

Comment: thanks!, but what if i want to pass another value from another input again?
<input type="hidden" value="{{ $keycart->nama_produk}}" name="nama_produk[]"/>
<input type="hidden" value="{{ $keycart->unit_produk}}" name="unit_produk[]"/>

something like that

Comment: you can pass the id as array key like  nama_produk[$keycart->id]. you will get the keycart->id in loop key foreach($request->nama_produk as $key => $row){}. in the example the $key is $keycart->id